# MYSQL connection with JDBC returns empty

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa, jdbc

I am following some Spring Boot tutorial. And I am trying to implement basic course student enrollment system. I created required tables on MySQL, but whenever I want to get data from one table result return empty.

```java
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "Students")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    
    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    
}
```

This is my entity.

```java
@Service
public class StudentService {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;
    
    public Student saveStudent(Student student) {
        return studentRepository.save(student);
    }
    public List<Student> getStudents(){
        return studentRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    public Student getStudentByID(int id) {
        return studentRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }
    
    public void deleteStudent(int id) {
        studentRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
    public Student updateStudent(Student student){
        Student existingStudent = studentRepository.findById(student.getId()).orElse(null);
        existingStudent.setName(student.getName());
        existingStudent.setEmail(student.getEmail());
        return studentRepository.save(existingStudent);
    }
}
```

**Note:** StudentRepository was extended from JpaRepository

Here are the application.properties file

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/StudentManagement
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Also I have the StudentController class. I use it to create restful api.

```java
@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:3000", "http://localhost:4200" })
public class StudentController {
    
    @Autowired
    StudentService studenService;
    
    
    @GetMapping("/students")
    public String check() {
        return "Hello world";
    }
    
    //get All Student
    @GetMapping("/getAllStudents")
    public List<Student> getAllStudent(){
    
        return studenService.getStudents();
    }
}
```

I add check() method to see whether API works or not (it's working). But getAllStudent method returns empty.
What could be cause this problem?

Comment: Have you checked if you actually have data in the database?

Comment: I have one student